# Java sum two double[][] with parallel stream

Tags: java, arrays, java-8, java-stream

Let's say I have this two matrices:

```
double[][] a = new double[2][2]
a[0][0] = 1
a[0][1] = 2
a[1][0] = 3
a[1][1] = 4

double[][] b = new double[2][2]
b[0][0] = 1
b[0][1] = 2
b[1][0] = 3
b[1][1] = 4
```

in the traditional way, to sum this matrices I would do a nested for loop:

```
int rows = a.length;
int cols = a[0].length;
double[][] res = new double[rows][cols];
for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < cols; j++){
        res[i][j] = a[i][j] + b[i][j];
    }
}
```

I'm fairly new to the stream API but I think this is a great fit to use with `parallelStream` so my question is if there's a way to do this and take advantage of parallel processing?

**Edit:** not sure if this is the right place but here we go:
Using some suggestions I putted the Stream to the test. The set up was like this:
Classical approach:

```
public class ClassicMatrix {

    private final double[][] components;
    private final int cols;
    private final int rows;




    public ClassicMatrix(final double[][] components){
    this.components = components;
    this.rows = components.length;
    this.cols = components[0].length;
    }


    public ClassicMatrix addComponents(final ClassicMatrix a) {
    final double[][] res = new double[rows][cols];
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < rows; j++) {
        res[i][j] = components[i][j] + a.components[i][j];
        }
    }
    return new ClassicMatrix(res);
    }

}
```

Using @dkatzel suggestion:

```
public class MatrixStream1 {

    private final double[][] components;
    private final int cols;
    private final int rows;

    public MatrixStream1(final double[][] components){
    this.components = components;
    this.rows = components.length;
    this.cols = components[0].length;
    }

    public MatrixStream1 addComponents(final MatrixStream1 a) {
    final double[][] res = new double[rows][cols];
    IntStream.range(0, rows*cols).parallel().forEach(i -> {
               int x = i/rows;
               int y = i%rows;

               res[x][y] = components[x][y] + a.components[x][y];
           });
    return new MatrixStream1(res);
    }
}
```

Using @Eugene suggestion:

```
public class MatrixStream2 {

    private final double[][] components;
    private final int cols;
    private final int rows;

    public MatrixStream2(final double[][] components) {
    this.components = components;
    this.rows = components.length;
    this.cols = components[0].length;
    }

    public MatrixStream2 addComponents(final MatrixStream2 a) {
    final double[][] res = new double[rows][cols];
    IntStream.range(0, rows)
        .forEach(i -> Arrays.parallelSetAll(res[i], j -> components[i][j] * a.components[i][j]));
    return new MatrixStream2(res);
    }
}
```

and a test class, running 3 independent times one for each method (just replacing the method name in main()):

```
public class MatrixTest {

    private final static String path = "/media/manuel/workspace/data/";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    final List<Double[]> lst = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 100; i < 8000; i = i + 400) {
        final Double[] d = testClassic(i); 
        System.out.println(d[0] + " : " + d[1]);
        lst.add(d);
    }
    IOUtils.saveToFile(path + "classic.csv", lst);
    }

    public static Double[] testClassic(final int i) {

    final ClassicMatrix a = new ClassicMatrix(rand(i));
    final ClassicMatrix b = new ClassicMatrix(rand(i));

    final long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    final ClassicMatrix mul = a.addComponents(b);
    final long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
    final double elapsed = (now - start);

    return new Double[] { (double) i, elapsed };

    }

    public static Double[] testStream1(final int i) {

    final MatrixStream1 a = new MatrixStream1(rand(i));
    final MatrixStream1 b = new MatrixStream1(rand(i));

    final long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    final MatrixStream1 mul = a.addComponents(b);
    final long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
    final double elapsed = (now - start);

    return new Double[] { (double) i, elapsed };

    }

    public static Double[] testStream2(final int i) {

    final MatrixStream2 a = new MatrixStream2(rand(i));
    final MatrixStream2 b = new MatrixStream2(rand(i));

    final long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    final MatrixStream2 mul = a.addComponents(b);
    final long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
    final double elapsed = (now - start);

    return new Double[] { (double) i, elapsed };

    }

    private static double[][] rand(final int size) {
    final double[][] rnd = new double[size][size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
        rnd[i][j] = Math.random();
        }
    }
    return rnd;
    }
}
```

The results:

```
Classic Matrix size, Time (ms)
100.0,1.0
500.0,5.0
900.0,5.0
1300.0,43.0
1700.0,94.0
2100.0,26.0
2500.0,33.0
2900.0,46.0
3300.0,265.0
3700.0,71.0
4100.0,87.0
4500.0,380.0
4900.0,432.0
5300.0,215.0
5700.0,238.0
6100.0,577.0
6500.0,677.0
6900.0,609.0
7300.0,584.0
7700.0,592.0

Stream1, Time(ms)
100.0,86.0
500.0,13.0
900.0,9.0
1300.0,47.0
1700.0,92.0
2100.0,29.0
2500.0,33.0
2900.0,46.0
3300.0,253.0
3700.0,71.0
4100.0,90.0
4500.0,352.0
4900.0,373.0
5300.0,497.0
5700.0,485.0
6100.0,579.0
6500.0,711.0
6900.0,800.0
7300.0,780.0
7700.0,902.0

Stream2, Time(ms)
100.0,111.0
500.0,42.0
900.0,12.0
1300.0,54.0
1700.0,97.0
2100.0,110.0
2500.0,177.0
2900.0,71.0
3300.0,250.0
3700.0,106.0
4100.0,359.0
4500.0,143.0
4900.0,233.0
5300.0,261.0
5700.0,289.0
6100.0,406.0
6500.0,814.0
6900.0,830.0
7300.0,828.0
7700.0,911.0
```

I made a plot for better comparison:
[image: Performance Test]

There's no improvement at all. Where's the flaw? Are the matrices to small  (7700 x 7700)? Greater than this it blows up my computer memory.

Comment: be vary that `parallelStream` has quite an overhead for splitting the stream up in chunks and later combining the intermedate results again into a single result

Comment: Perhaps: `IntStream.range(0, rows).parallel().forEach(i -> IntStream.range(0, cols).parallel().forEach(j -> res[i][j] = a[i][j] + b[i][j]));` but I'm not sure about the performance gain, because thread overhead or because you can not take advantage of cpu's cache.

Comment: :), if you want the high performance, you need a `Martrix` class and calculate 2 `Martrix`s lazily, e.g: `martrix3 = martrix1.add(martrix2)`.

Comment: it's just probably the way you test... I've put up a JMH test here https://gist.github.com/wind57/4755743a8875b9b60b6b15d75b3eb7dc. Federico's second approach is the fastest

Comment: In my experience, if your math is so complicated you need to parallelize it, you should get some graphics cards. They're really freaking good at parallelizing math.

Comment: With such tiny matrices and such simple operations you are only going to see performance **degrade** if you use parallel processing; the cost of thread scheduling vastly outweighs any parallel processing gain (by many orders of magnitude). If your arrays have at least 1000 entries, you *might* see a performance gain using parallel processing. I would try with 10K+.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One way to do it would be by using [`Arrays.parallelSetAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#parallelSetAll-int:A-java.util.function.IntUnaryOperator-):

```
int rows = a.length;
int cols = a[0].length;
double[][] res = new double[rows][cols];

Arrays.parallelSetAll(res, i -> {
    Arrays.parallelSetAll(res[i], j -> a[i][j] + b[i][j]);
    return res[i];
});
```

I'm not 100% sure, but I think the inner call to `Arrays.parallelSetAll` might not be worth the overhead of generating inner parallelization for each row's columns. Maybe it's just enough to parallelize the sum for each row only:

```
Arrays.parallelSetAll(res, i -> {
    Arrays.setAll(res[i], j -> a[i][j] + b[i][j]);
    return res[i];
});
```

Anyway, you should measure carefully before adding parallelization to an algorithm, because many times the overhead is so big that it's not worth using it.

Comment: you're right... the second one is faster - at least up to 3000 * 3000 - that's what i am running some tests with

Comment: you're second approach is the fastest one of all solutions here. read my answer for the link...

Comment: @Eugene Thank you very much for your tests, I'll be happy to read and try them as soon as I can. I had already upvoted your answer, so...

Comment: You're doing something different from the OP: You're replacing the inner arrays by new ones instead of just modifying them. By avoiding this, it should get faster, shouldn't it?

Comment: @maaartinus No, I'm just setting the sum at each cell.

Comment: You're right and I can't read.... you're assigning `res[i] = res[i]`, which I missed completely. I'd bet, the assigment gets eliminated by the JIT, otherwise I'd propose `IntStream.range(0, a.length).parallel()
.forEach(i -> Arrays.setAll(res[i], j -> a[i][j] + b[i][j]);` which might be cleaner.

Comment: @maaartinus I bet there's no difference in performance, just a matter of style

Comment: Maybe, there’s a gain in not zero filling the arrays in advance, `double[][] res = new double[rows][]; Arrays.parallelSetAll(res, i -> { double[] newArr = new double[cols]; Arrays.setAll(newArr, j -> a[i][j] + b[i][j]); return newArr; });`

Comment: …and not doing a row access for every cell `double[][] res = new double[rows][];   Arrays.parallelSetAll(res, i -> { double[] newArr = new double[cols], aRow=a[i], bRow=b[i]; Arrays.setAll(newArr, j -> aRow[j] + bRow[j]); return newArr; });`

Comment: @Holger it sounds like your suggestions would actually improve the tests. I will try it this afternoon. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

This is yet to measured (I will a bit later), but shouldn't the already build in `Arrays.parallelSetAll` do the job in a fastest way?

```
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
        int j = i;
        Arrays.parallelSetAll(r[j], x -> a[j][x] + b[j][x]);
    }
```

Or even nicer:

```
IntStream.range(0, a.length)
         .forEach(i -> Arrays.parallelSetAll(r[i], j -> a[i][j] + b[i][j]));
```

This plays very nice with CPU caches as well, since the probability that the next entry is in the same cache line is big. Doing the read in the reverse order (columns and rows), will disperse the reads all over the place.

I've put a jmh test [here](https://gist.github.com/wind57/4755743a8875b9b60b6b15d75b3eb7dc).  Notice that [Federico's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45304215/java-sum-two-double-with-parallel-stream/45309905#45309905) is the fastest. Go up vote his idea.

Here are the results:

```
Benchmark                 (howManyEntries)  Mode  Cnt    Score    Error  Units
DoubleArraySum.dkatzel                 100  avgt   10    0.055 ±  0.005  ms/op
DoubleArraySum.dkatzel                 500  avgt   10    0.997 ±  0.156  ms/op
DoubleArraySum.dkatzel                1000  avgt   10    4.162 ±  0.368  ms/op
DoubleArraySum.dkatzel                3000  avgt   10   39.619 ±  4.391  ms/op
DoubleArraySum.dkatzel                8000  avgt   10  236.468 ± 41.599  ms/op
DoubleArraySum.eugene                  100  avgt   10    0.671 ±  0.187  ms/op
DoubleArraySum.eugene                  500  avgt   10    6.317 ±  0.268  ms/op
DoubleArraySum.eugene                 1000  avgt   10   14.751 ±  0.676  ms/op
DoubleArraySum.eugene                 3000  avgt   10   65.174 ±  6.044  ms/op
DoubleArraySum.eugene                 8000  avgt   10  285.571 ± 23.206  ms/op
DoubleArraySum.federico1               100  avgt   10    0.169 ±  0.010  ms/op
DoubleArraySum.federico1               500  avgt   10    1.999 ±  0.217  ms/op
DoubleArraySum.federico1              1000  avgt   10    6.087 ±  1.108  ms/op
DoubleArraySum.federico1              3000  avgt   10   40.825 ±  4.853  ms/op
DoubleArraySum.federico1              8000  avgt   10  267.446 ± 37.490  ms/op
DoubleArraySum.federico2               100  avgt   10    0.034 ±  0.003  ms/op
DoubleArraySum.federico2               500  avgt   10    0.974 ±  0.152  ms/op
DoubleArraySum.federico2              1000  avgt   10    3.245 ±  0.080  ms/op
DoubleArraySum.federico2              3000  avgt   10   30.503 ±  5.960  ms/op
DoubleArraySum.federico2              8000  avgt   10  183.183 ± 21.861  ms/op
DoubleArraySum.holijava                100  avgt   10    0.063 ±  0.002  ms/op
DoubleArraySum.holijava                500  avgt   10    1.112 ±  0.020  ms/op
DoubleArraySum.holijava               1000  avgt   10    4.138 ±  0.062  ms/op
DoubleArraySum.holijava               3000  avgt   10   41.784 ±  1.029  ms/op
DoubleArraySum.holijava               8000  avgt   10  266.590 ±  4.080  ms/op
DoubleArraySum.pivovarit               100  avgt   10    0.112 ±  0.002  ms/op
DoubleArraySum.pivovarit               500  avgt   10    2.427 ±  0.075  ms/op
DoubleArraySum.pivovarit              1000  avgt   10    9.572 ±  0.355  ms/op
DoubleArraySum.pivovarit              3000  avgt   10   84.413 ±  2.197  ms/op
DoubleArraySum.pivovarit              8000  avgt   10  690.942 ± 34.993  ms/op
```

**EDIT**

here is a more readable output (federico wins with all inputs)

```
100=[federico2, dkatzel, holijava, pivovarit, federico1, eugene]
500=[federico2, dkatzel, holijava, federico1, pivovarit, eugene]
1000=[federico2, holijava, dkatzel, federico1, pivovarit, eugene]
3000=[federico2, dkatzel, federico1, holijava, eugene, pivovarit]
8000=[federico2, dkatzel, holijava, federico1, eugene, pivovarit]
```

Comment: good job. thanks for your test, but I have up yours. I can't do it again. :(

Comment: Eugene, could you please explain what it means to have an error greater than the average?

Comment: Besides, I think a full sequential test is missing, so we can establish a base line. I suspect it will be the fastest of all...

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner an error greater then the result could mean different things, *lots* of them I don't even know' but that is never an indication of something good... I'll look at the tests again and see if I spot anything

Comment: Great job!  I try to reproduce your benchmark, but I added the "simple" way (non- parallel) my results: https://pastebin.com/JPurPzNn

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner I've ran the same tests, but this time I have run it for about 4 hours - having *lots and lots* of warm-up iterations.  The results are much cleaner.

Comment: thanks, but why mine is lower than `dkatzel`. since mine is same as `federico2`.

Comment: @holi-java I'm not sure, but it is not *exactly* the same btw - look at the link, I had to edit them slightly to  work with `jmh`... May be I messed up things a bit - check yourself.

Comment: it doesn't matter. I only want to know why. thanks very much. I know mine is lower than `federico2`, maybe it will consuming additional `IntStream`s in nested `map`. but I don't know why mine is lower than `dkatzel`.

Comment: I'd also be curious about are purely sequential test. In many cases, parallelization does not play out well when it comes to embarassingly trivial parallelization of *a single addition* ...

Comment: @Marco13 sure... I'll update this post when I do them

Comment: @Marco13 the *only* case where parallel makes sense (at least in my tests) is the `8000 * 8000` matrix - but even then it wins from an imperative way by up to `15ms` out of `155-165` total. I would say - pretty much expected.

Answer (score 6):

The only option I see here is to more/less generate all possible pairs of indexes and then extract elements and apply summation. Using parallel streams will not have any additional positive effect here with such small example but you can surely utilize Stream API here(and convert to parallel if needed immediately), although the result is not that nice as expected:

```
IntStream.range(0, a.length).boxed()
      .flatMap(i -> IntStream.range(0, a[0].length)
        .mapToObj(j -> new AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry<>(i, j)))
      .parallel()
      .forEach(e -> {
          res[e.getKey()][e.getValue()]
            = a[e.getKey()][e.getValue()] + b[e.getKey()][e.getValue()];
      });
```

We need to introduce a middleman(middlepair?) so that we can parallelize one `Stream` and not play with parallelized nested `Streams`.

Another advanced way would be to implement your own custom collector but it will still involve nested looping at some point.

---

The true power of Stream API can be observed when trying to sum all values from two arrays:

```
Stream.concat(Arrays.stream(a), Arrays.stream(b)).parallel()
      .flatMapToDouble(Arrays::stream)
      .sum();
```

Comment: I made a huge mistake. I am not sure why people are upvoting. Let me change that.

Comment: you can delete your answer if you think it is wrong

Comment: This is a simple example but suppose instead of a `double[2][2]` I have a `double[10000][10000]` and instead of a sum I want to multiply? there's no gain in parallel stream?

Comment: @MLeiria there is with my answer

Comment: @MLeiria There is a great parallel algorithm for multiply big matrices: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication_algorithm

Comment: Do you mean `Stream.concat(Arrays.stream(a), Arrays.stream(b)).parallel() .flatMapToDouble(Arrays::stream) .sum()`?

Comment: @holger cool, did not realize the existence of such a specialized method :)

Answer (score 3):

You could use an `IntStream` to make a stream over the number of cells in the matrix and then do some math to convert that int into a matrix location.

```
IntStream.range(0, rows*cols)
               .parallel()
               .forEach( i->{
                   int x = i/rows;
                   int y = i%rows;

                   res[x][y] = a[x][y] + b[x][y];
               });
```

Other answers to this question are not only wrong (at the time of this writing) but create multiple Streams which affects performance and are also not even parallel

As @Holger points out, while this single stream might be easier to read the performance costs of divisions and modulus will make it slower than a Stream of Streams with only additions until there are many cores.  I'm not sure how many will be needed to compensate

Comment: The remaining question is, how many cores do you need to compensate the introduction of division/modulo to an operation that previously consisted of a sole addition…

Comment: @Holger that is true, I was going for  single Stream solution but you're right it would be slower than a stream of streams

Comment: Or not using a stream for the inner operation: `IntStream.range(0, res.length).forEach(i -> Arrays.parallelSetAll(res[i], j -> a[i][j] + b[i][j]));`

Comment: @Holger doesn't `paraellelSetAll` use a Stream internally?

Comment: It may or may not; that’s an implementation detail. But the code using it is quiet concise.

Comment: @Holger it's also probably important to note, that if you reverse the reading of rows and columns - there will be lots of caches misses too.

Answer (score 3):

How about this?

```
double[][] res = IntStream.range(0, a.length).parallel()
                          .mapToObj(i -> 
                                  IntStream.range(0, a[i].length)
                                           .mapToDouble(j -> a[i][j] + b[i][j])
                                           .toArray()
                          )
                          .toArray(double[][]::new);

System.out.println(res);
//                  ^--- [[2., 4.], [6., 8.]]
```

Comment: Great answer! In my benchmarks this has the best performance by large: pastebin.com/JPurPzNn

Comment: @DavidPérezCabrera thanks for your test. Indeed, my approach is same as @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner's second approach. I think it is faster in large martrixs since maybe it's return a chunk row in the nested `IntStream` rather  rather each `cell` and without any additional `requireNotNull` checkings.